# How to use glClearBufferData to initialize a buffer

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

```
GLuint buffer;
glCreateBuffers(1, &buffer);
glNamedBufferStorage(buffer, 1024, NULL, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
unsigned int x = 0x01010101;
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

glClearBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_R32UI, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &x);
int* p = (int*)glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cout << hex << p[i] << " ";
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

However, the output is '1010102' rather than '1010101'.

Comment: If you're using DSA functions, you should use them consistently. This means `glClearNamedBufferData` and `glMapNamedBufferRange`.

Comment: It doesn't work. The output is the same as before.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to fix this problem. It's just better code to be consistent about the APIs you're using. Also, have you tried checking for OpenGL errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> glClearBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_R32UI, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &x);
> ```

The proper format parameter should be `GL_RED_INTEGER`, not `GL_RED`.